# Check if one date column is there in another date column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 date columns. Is there a way to find of COlB is existing in COlA or not.

Example

```
df
ColA          ColB
2010-10-14   2010-09-28
2010-10-15   2010-10-31
2010-09-28   2010-11-20
```

Expected Output

```
df
ColA          ColB          COLC
2010-10-14   2010-09-28     Existing in ColA
2010-10-15   2010-10-31     No
2010-09-28   2010-11-20     No
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ifelse` :

```
df <- transform(df, ColC = ifelse(ColB %in% ColA, 'Existing in colA', 'No'))
df
#        ColA       ColB             ColC
#1 2010-10-14 2010-09-28 Existing in colA
#2 2010-10-15 2010-10-31               No
#3 2010-09-28 2010-11-20               No
```

Same logic without `ifelse` can be written as :

```
df <- transform(df, ColC = c('No', 'Existing in colA')[ColB %in% ColA + 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another way just quite similar to the one dear Ronak Shah posted by with some minor differences:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tribble(
  ~ColA,          ~ColB,
  2010-10-14,   2010-09-28,
  2010-10-15,   2010-10-31,
  2010-09-28,   2010-11-20
)

df %>%
  mutate(is_exist = map_lgl(ColB, ~ ifelse(any(.x %in% ColA), TRUE, NA)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
   ColA  ColB is_exist
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
1  1986  1973 TRUE    
2  1985  1969 NA      
3  1973  1979 NA
```

I assumed that we are checking whether any values from column `ColB` exists among values in column `ColA`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(ColC = case_when(ColB %in% ColA ~ 'Existing in colA', TRUE ~ 'No'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `match` + `is.na`

```
transform(
  df,
  ColC = c("Existing in ColA", "No")[is.na(match(ColB, ColA)) + 1]
)
```